# When loading a saved sequential model I get a warning about the model lacking input shape and optimizer state resetting

Tags: tf.keras

I have a model of two LSTMs and a dense layer on top. When I save the model and reload it for more training, I get a warning: Sequential models without an `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
I don't understand why I get this warning as I define an input shape in the model.

```py
# create data feeder from (1m,6) and (30k,3) datasets
def windowed_dataset(series, results, window_size=120, batch_size=1024):
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((series, results))
    data = data.apply(sliding.sliding_window_batch(window_size=window_size, window_shift=1))
    data = data.shuffle(series.shape[0]-window_size+1, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
    return data.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1).repeat()


from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import sliding

# data feeder to model
shuffled_train=windowed_dataset(x_train, y_train)
shuffled_valid=windowed_dataset(x_valid, y_valid)

# model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,input_shape=(120,6), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer="adam", metrics=["mae"])

model.fit(shuffled_train, steps_per_epoch=987, epochs=10, validation_data=shuffled_valid, validation_steps=32 )

print(model.summary())
model.save('//temp/my_lines.h5')

#continue training
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('//temp/my_lines.h5')
model.fit(shuffled_train, steps_per_epoch=987, epochs=1, validation_data=shuffled_valid, validation_steps=32 )
```

After model load, the error rate I achieve during the first run is lost and it starts training fresh, how can I get it to continue from where it left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found the answer. The input shape needs to be specified as a layer, and not added as a parameter to the otherwise first layer.

So, instead of

```py
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,input_shape=(120,6), return_sequences=True)))
```

it should be in two lines:

```py
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(120, 6)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
```